# PHP Pull Subordinate Info in Get function

Tags: php, get

I'm a complete newb to PHP - I tried researching this problem, but haven't found an answer.  I'm using Formstack to create an order form for a non-profit.  At the end of the process, formstack appends all of the entered data to the URL.  Typically, I use a simple PHP GET to pull the information I need.  In this instance, however, there is a second layer of data after the = of the primary item's name.

Each item shows up similar to this (example items is Chickens):

&chickens=charge_type+%3D+fixed_amount%0Aquantity+%3D+2%0Aunit_price+%3D+15.00%0Atotal+%3D+30&

I need to pull quantity=2, where quantity is a subordinate value of chickens.  My knowledge ends at pulling the entire string following chickens=

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["chickens"]); ?>
```

Which results in: charge_type = fixed_amount quantity = 2 unit_price = 15.00 total = 30

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's urlencoded.  Try urldecode(), perhaps on $_GET['chickens'], perhaps more likely on $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].

Comment: It should be obvious from the output of the code fragment you provided how to parse the request. Try posting the code you are using (and for the benefit of the people who might want to help you, the output you got running that PHP against that query string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are going to do, you could transform the values in Chicken Array form:

```
// separate all the value-key pairs in chicken into an array
$array = explode("\n", $_GET["chickens"]);

// init an array that will store all values as associative array
$chickens = array();

foreach($array as $valuepair) {
    // go too the key-value-pairs and split them at the "=" char
    $tmp = explode("=", $valuepair);
    // add value under keyname to array and remove some spaces with trim function 
    $chickens[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
}

// show what we got as key-values, as debug output 
print_r($chickens);

// show one value of the array
echo $chickens['quantity'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - this results in: Array ( [charge_type] => fixed_amount [quantity] => 2 [unit_price] => 15.00 [total] => 30 ), how would I then narrow it down to show the quantity or unit_price?

Comment: @user1424269 see my updated answer, how to echo a single value of that array. Later you have to remove the print_r.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Working very well!